# How to send -Dflag to android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there a way to send -D directives to an android app? On desktop java I would just do java -Dsomeflag=value.

How would you do this on android? I am building with eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to do this because you want to have conditional `if` blocks for debugging.  You can set `android:debuggable="true"` in your manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:name=".SomeApp"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
```

and then test for it like this:

```
if(Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "some log statement");
}
```

Comment: You are correct this is for debug code. Does this flag carry onto an actual device?

Comment: Yes, it does carry onto devices.